# bootstrap column class and z-index

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created an angularjs directive that pops up a div when you click a textbox and shows a calendar. I don't believe this is angular issue though but more of a bootstrap issue. I have controls under the calendar textbox and I want the calendar div to show up over those controls. I set it's z-index to a high number but I noticed if the controls under it have any "col-*" on it, they show up on top always. Is there any way I can get my calendar div to always show up on top?

https://plnkr.co/edit/CmFXd40oeuztl4qHIZQO?p=preview

```
    <hol-calendar style="z-index: 9999;" returned-day="Monday" on-change="vm.dateChange(dt)" initial-date="vm.myDate"></hol-calendar>

    <div class="row" style="z-index: 0">
      <label class="">Monday:</label>
      <input style="z-index: 0;" class="col-md-2 input-sm" type="time" placeholder="HH:mm" ng-required="false" />
      <label class="col-md-1 text-primary control-label" > until </label>
      <input class="col-md-2 input-sm" type="time" placeholder="HH:mm" ng-required="false" />
      <input class="col-md-1" type="checkbox" name="ClosedMonday" data-element-name="Monday" />
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: one solution is to add "position:absolute" to the hol-calendar. this will put it above the bootstrap inputs.

Comment: I set that position value in the outer most div of the template and it worked! Thanks Trob!

Comment: You're welcome! You may want to be selective with where you're using "position:absolute" as it can make styling sloppy and complicated. I'd think the only place you would need it is on the calendar element.